# C# Serialize Generic Wrapper class

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, reflection

I'm trying to implement JSON serialization for an `Optional` wrapper class. I want the serialization to be akin to a nullable type, so:

```
"myOptional": null
```

for null, and

```
"myOptional": 2
```

or

```
"myOptional": { . . . }
```

for objects.

This is fine until I get to a wrapped object, I don't know how to tell the serializer to "serialize this object like you normally would". The Microsoft docs lead me to believe that I have to implement `JsonConverterFactory`, but I don't know how to tell the writer to serialize the inner object automatically.

```
public class OptionalTypeJsonConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert
            .GetGenericArguments()[0].IsClass;
    }

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(
        Type type,
        JsonSerializerOptions options
    )
    {
        return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(
            type: typeof(OptionalJsonConverter<>).MakeGenericType(type.GenericTypeArguments[0]),
            bindingAttr: BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
            binder: null,
            args: new object[] { options },
            culture: null
        )!;
    }

    private class OptionalJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<Optional<T>>
        where T : struct
    {
        public OptionalJsonConverter(JsonSerializerOptions options) { }

        public override Optional<T>? Read(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type typeToConvert,
            JsonSerializerOptions options
        )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            Optional<T> optional,
            JsonSerializerOptions options
        )
        {
            if (optional.IsNone())
            {
                writer.WriteNullValue();
            }
            else
            {
                // don't know what to put here. I want to serialize objects as if the wrapper was never there.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How should I go about achieving this?
As an example, if `Optional<T>` has `T = MyClass` and `MyClass` is

```
{
  public int ID { get; set; } = 2
  public string Name { get; set; } = "myname"
}
```

then I want this to serialize to

```
"optionalofMyClass": 
{
  "ID": 2,
  "Name": "myname"
}
```

Comment: What is the wrapper class? Is there a reason why it doesn't serialize without doing some extra work? I'm guessing that's the case but if would be easier to answer if we could see the thing you're trying to serialize.

Comment: It does serialize, but it serializes with the wrapper's property name, like: `"myWrapper": { "value":  2 } }` instead of `"{myWrapper": 2}`. You could  consider the class as `Optional<T> { T value }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by doing the below.

Adding this method to `Optional<T>`

```
private T? _value { get; }
. . . 
internal string Serialize()
{
  return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(_value);
}
```

and in the `OptionalTypeJsonConverterFactory`, I changed

```
        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            Optional<T> optional,
            JsonSerializerOptions options
        )
        {
            if (optional.IsNone())
            {
                writer.WriteNullValue();
            }
            else
            {
                // don't know what to put here. I want to serialize objects as if the wrapper was never there.
            }
        }
```

to

```
        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            Optional<T> optional,
            JsonSerializerOptions options
        )
        {
            if (optional.IsNone())
            {
                writer.WriteNullValue();
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteRawValue(optional.Serialize());
            }
        }
```

this essentially skips serializing `Optional<T>` and directly serializes its `_value`

This works for ASP.NET endpoint serialization which was the problem I was looking to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you want to serialize your object whether or not it has a value. If its not having a value, it should show as null, and when it does, it should the nested json structure. I tried with below code

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person p1 = new Person {Id = 1, Name = "User1"};
        var output1 = new Wrapper<Person>(p1);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(output1));
        
        Person p2 = new Person();
        var output2 = new Wrapper<Person>(p2);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(output2));
        
        Person p3 = null;
        var output3 = new Wrapper<Person>(p3);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(output3));
    }
}

public class Wrapper<T> where T : class {
    public T optionalOfMyClass { get; set; }
    public Wrapper(T data) {
        optionalOfMyClass = data;
    }
}

public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The output would look like:

```
{"optionalOfMyClass":{"Id":1,"Name":"User1"}}
{"optionalOfMyClass":{"Id":0}}
{"optionalOfMyClass":null}
```

Find the dotnet fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7DVF7c).

Comment: This does work, but is there a way to implement this using the typical `[JsonConverter]` attribute style? I could do this with ToString, but the I run into the problem that the property isn't always called "Wrapper", it would depend on the calling scope

Comment: Yes you can. It was just an example to get the desired output. You may assign the wrapper<T> to another your desired object and then serializing it would get the output without needing the `ToString()` overriding and explicitly having the "Wrapper" object. Its purely based on how you want your json output to be Like, employee = Wrapper<Person> then output would be ```{"employee": {...}}```;

Comment: Could you type up that example? I'm having trouble visualizing how the serializer would know what to do

Comment: Updated the code above now and as well as in the fiddle (possibly to reflect). The output shows multiple json outcomes based on your T type class setup with decoration of Json attributes to it.

Comment: This is what I'm aiming to do, I want to essentially skip the middle value of `optionalOfMyClass`: 
`"wrapper": {"Id":1,"Name":"User1"}}
"wrapper": {"Id":0, "Name": null}
"wrapper": null`

Comment: I am still unclear from your last comment. Pasting the json on the comment didn't get it formatted to explain whether its your desired output or the output you want to avoid. Can you share me what is your expected/desired output?

Comment: I've found a solution, I'll post it here soon. That may clarify what I was trying to do